# Magento connect issue when trying to load ANY extentions

Tags: magento-connect, ce-1.9.2.0

I was wondering if anyone else was having the same issue:
community/Locale_Mage_community_fr_FR: Unknown cipher in list: TLSv1

Was trying to load the French language extention as well as other one's but ufortunately came up with the above error. We had no changes on the server or anything else, other versions are working fine.

The only thing we had done different was URL re-writes (which after deletion did not change anything) as well as different URL assigned to store views (DE,FR,PL, etc have their own URL's).

We uploaded it to test the new Magento but it seems to cause problems.

Anyone has a clue on how to approach this issue?

Comment: Same Here! Site is blank...